# Parsing formatted text with jsoup

Tags: jsoup

i am trying to parse html text with jsoup. I have for example the following line in html.

```
<p align='left'><font size='12.0pt'><u><i><b>A bold italic underlined text:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br></b></i></u></font><font size='12.0pt'><i><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></i></font><font size='9.0pt'><i> </i></font><font size='9.0pt'><b>This is only Bold&nbsp;&nbsp;</i></font><font size='9.0pt'><i> </i></font><font size='9.0pt'><i><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></i></font><font size='9.0pt'>this is a simple line with white spaces at the end and at the beginnig&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></p>
```

How can i extract the text with formatting informations like bold, underlined and font-size etc...

i have tried to iterate through all elements and find TextNodes, no success.

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want just the content of `<p…>…</p>`?

Comment: i can get the content of <p…>…</p> with document.text(). what i want is to get all the formatting information of a text for example this part....<font size='12.0pt'><u><i><b>A bold italic underlined text:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br></b></i></u></font>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this by [**selecting**](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) the **child's** of `<p>…</p>`:

```
Document doc = ...
Element content = doc.select("p > *").first();
```

The selector `p > *` gives you the direct children of `<p>…</p>`.

**Result:**

```
<font size="12.0pt"><u><i><b>A bold italic underlined text:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br></b></i></u></font>
```

Comment: This is perfect :) I use now a for loop to go through elements and can use 'element.select("font").first()' 'element.select("u").first()' to find the formatting information for that element. But one more question, is there any select statement to check/find elemets which contains **<br> at the begininng** e.g. '<font size="12.0pt"><u><i><b><br>A bold italic</b></i></u></font>'

Comment: Yes, but i think you need to handle the `<br>` on a node basis, as it does not wrap it's elements. It also possible to select the `<br>`'s and take their parent element instead. However, that's a new question.